# Custom keyboard writting on a sequential text using buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard

I designed a custom keyboard using `ImageButton`s for Android (using Eclipse). I want to click on a button to write on the text, but every time I click a button, it resets the text, erasing what I previously wrote.

How can I get it to continue writing from the previous text?

This is a basic bit of my code, using two buttons and a text field.

```
package com.example.nonachan;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    char g;
    char h;

    int i = 0; 

    //char buf[] = new char[10];    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText t =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);

             ImageButton n = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b1);            
            n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    g = 'd';
                    // buf[i] = 'd';
                      t.setText( "" + g);  
                     i++;
                }       

            });

            ImageButton a = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b2);
            a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //   buf[i] = 'h';
                     h = 'h' ;
                     t.setText( "" +h); 
                     i++; 

                }
            });

            Button l = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
            l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

                }

            });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t.setText( "" + g);
```

The above line in your code says to set `t`'s text to `"" + g` which is equal to `"d"`. It will never append the text since you don't tell it to.

Try adding the existing text in the text field:

```
t.setText(t.getText().toString() + g);
```

And you'll have to do the same with `t.setText( "" +h);` as well.

Comment: @elektranona If the answer helped solve your issue, you can click the checkmark on the left to mark it as "accepted". Good luck with your project! :)